# Is there a cIommand line (or powershell) command that, when tyoed in, will display the Win 10 clipboard (WIN + V)?

Tags: command

I need to be able to display the Win 10 clipboard (WIN key + V).
BUT, from a command line.

Is such a thing possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Powershell cmdlet Get-Clipboard does what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am trying to involke the Clipboard UI itself so the end user can do whatever it is they want to do with it. 
Go ahead, hold down the WIN key and then press the V kez.
 See what appears.
Its that UI that I want to appear, not to acquire the contents of the Clipboard.